# the easiest way to get the rawQuery result to the main activity

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio I'm selecting all rows from a SQLite table and want to pass all the data to the main activity but the app stops and I think it's because I'm using the arrays incorrectly. What's the easiest way to get the rawQuery result to the main activity?

//In DatabaseAccess.java:

```
public String[][] getEveryRecord() {
    Cursor cursorTwo = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM positionsTable", null);
    cursorTwo.moveToFirst();
    String[][] myRecords = new String[cursorTwo.getCount()][4];
    int i = 0;
    while (!cursorTwo.isAfterLast()) {
        i++;
        myRecords[i][0] = Integer.toString(cursorTwo.getInt(0));
        myRecords[i][1] = cursorTwo.getString(1);
        myRecords[i][2] = Float.toString(cursorTwo.getFloat(2));
        myRecords[i][3] = Float.toString(cursorTwo.getFloat(3));
        cursorTwo.moveToNext();
    }
    cursorTwo.close();
    return myRecords;
}
```

//In MainActivity.java:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
String[][] everyRecord = databaseAccess.getEveryRecord();
    databaseAccess.close();
    for(int row=0; row < everyRecord.length; row++) {
    String myPlace = everyRecord[row][1];
            double myLat = Double.parseDouble(everyRecord[row][2]);
            double myLng = Double.parseDouble(everyRecord[row][3]);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLat, myLng)).title(myPlace));
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Where exactly does it stop? Do you get a stacktrace?

Comment: My knowledge of error handling is very limited. Found this, does it help?  06-21 17:20:48.437  31267-31267/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..........MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Comment: Yes, that's part of a stacktrace, and there you have it already ... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ... which means, you are trying to access an array outside of its bounds. Somewhere in your stacktrace is a line number, which tells you where in your code the error happened... if you are working with Andoid Studio, you can just double click the error.

Comment: That led me right - I just needed to move i++; to start iterating the array at 0 instead.... Many thanks for your help!